# Comma's appearing in value returned by custom Ansible lookup plugin

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to write a small lookup plugin to return a timestamp + 1 day.

It was mostly to practice, however it seems off the bat I've hit an issue.

It seems that each character is separated by a comma when output in Ansible (via the debug module).

The lookup plugin itself is:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from ansible.plugins.lookup import LookupBase


# Small plugin to return time + 1 day
class LookupModule(LookupBase):
    def run(self, terms, variables, **kwargs):
        dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
        return dt.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
```

Placed in ./lookup_plugins/tomorrow.py.

The play being run is:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test: "{{ lookup('tomorrow') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test
```

The current result is:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************

ok: [localhost] => {
    "test": "2,0,1,9,0,2,0,6,T,1,5,1,6,3,7"
}
```

If I modify the python file to just print the output, I correctly get the string without comma's.

Just a note, I realise functionally I can just do:

```
"{{ lookup('pipe','date -d \"1 day\" +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S') }}"
```

However at this point I'm curious to learn what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However at this point I'm curious to learn what's happening.

It is because you are returning a string, which is a `list` of one character long `str` in Python, and thus when `LookupBase` (or whomever) tries to iterate over the output of `run()`, it turns into `["h","e","l","l","o"]` type deal.

I didn't check [them all](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/v2.7.5/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup), but I checked about 4-5 of them, and all the ones I found [return a `list`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.5/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/file.py#L65)

I consider it a documentation bug that the only way anyone could guess that `run` is designed to return multiple things is from the [plural "strings"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.5/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/__init__.py#L102) mentioned in its pydoc. Feel free to file a [bug in ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues) to let them know about your experience

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. Appreciate the URLs and the time you spent!

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. Lookup plugins are historically usually used to pipe result into loops. So Ansible expects to see a list.

You can wrap your return value into a list, like:

```
return [dt.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")]
```

This way, you'll get result you expect with `lookup('tomorrow')`.

Also note that `lookup` can be soon deprecated in favour of `query`. See [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#query).